# Infra level telemetry of a micro-service application built with MS Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, microservices, azure-service-fabric, telemetry

I am working on a micro-service application build in MS Azure Service Fabric. I need to gather infra level telemetry of the cluster and its nodes in real time and create Power BI queries so that i can prepare charts for the telemetry in Power BI Dashboard. I cannot use OMS due to its high cost. I was hoping to use Elastic Search but any other tools if also fine.

Thanks in advance.

Application Insights will only log information about the application. I need to capture Infrastructure related details here. Details like, downtime of a certain node on cluster, location of cluster a particular micro-service is hosted on, amount of traffic on different cluster, and so on

Comment: Does it need to be shown in Power BI, otherwise I would also suggest [Azure Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/). I made a repo you can take a look at for even more integration options in App. Insights, see https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring

Comment: Application Insights will only log information about the application. I need to capture Infrastructure related details here. Details like, downtime of a certain node on cluster, location of  cluster a particular micro-service is hosted on, amount of traffic on different cluster, and so on

Comment: Well, of course the monitoring of downtime can only be done by a process out of the cluster. But for all the other things you can still use App Ins. You can enrich the telemetry with the cluster and node details. If you take a look at my repo you can see a lot of details are added to the telemetry. Also using the Live Stream feature you have a realtime overview of the load on the server and the amount of traffic.